# Corrupt BIOS and no post screen

Tags: bios, cmos

I have an *Asus m2n sli deluxe* mainboard. I ran the Asus update utility (wish I didn't, it is buggy) and it started to loop (my OS is Windows 7 Pro 64-bit). after 15 minutes, I restarted my PC. as I expected the BIOS became corrupted. on boot, the screen shows nothing, no post screen, no buzzer sound, nothing!. so, I cleared the CMOS but I still get no response (I'm sure the jumper is at the correct position).

is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably, this motherboard seems to be very iffy when it comes to BIOS updates - I trashed one about 3 weeks ago trying to flash it.

The board is supposed to have a 'crashfree' BIOS and the recovery instructions (which I tried without success) are outlined here (different board variant, but same procedure): http://www.motherboardpoint.com/m2n32-sli-deluxe-wireless-and-bios-update-problems-t61048.html give it a go - hopefully it will work for you.

I was able to grab a replacement BIOS chip from an identical duff board we were just about to scrap for other reasons, but they are also available on ebay for about 10 UK pounds.

Edit: Position of BIOS in socket (circled), below CMOS battery:

[image: M2N SLI motherboard]

Comment: i read the solution at the link you provided. oh, the horror! besides not having a PCI video card, i'm not sure if i got the discharging myself onto the chassis part. i am pretty sure that i cannot solder another bios chip, too. thanks for the solution though. this card is as good as junk now! oh, you monstrous ASUS update utility how i hate you and if i had known you were so buggy!

Comment: @sterz: Do check again as my BIOS was in a socket so no soldering required.

Comment: here is a picture of my bios: http://i.imgur.com/pVKny.jpg do you think it is socketed? it looked to me that it is soldered.

Comment: @sterz: You're right that's soldered directly to the board. Darn.